# Hibernate Inheritance overriding

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, mapping

I have two class `Author` and `User` like these:

```
 public class Author {
         protected int id;
         protected String firstName;
         protected List<Journal> Journals;

         //constructors ...
         //getters and setter ...
};


public class User extends Author {
             protected List<Affiliations> affiliations; 
             //constructors ...
             //getters and setter ...
    };
```

I have mapped them using xml using `joined-subclass`. And The problem I am facing is that whenever I create an Author, and want to load all the User, the Author is appearing, which is not what I expect.

Here is the mapping file, without the properties

```
<class name="Author" table="AUTHOR">
        <id name="id" type="int" access="field">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <joined-subclass name="User" extends="Author" table="USER" lazy="false">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
        </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

Comment: Well maybe you should post the code that loads all users.

Comment: I am sure the problem is not coming from there, I have found the answer , and post it, thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have figured out what the problem was, though I am not sure why it was a problem.

So the problem was the class of the generator, wich was to `assign` and now is `generated`